# Como criar um link blob no PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, vídeo, blob, longblob

Oi!
Bem, estou criando um site de vídeos estou com um problema para reproduzir os vídeos, coloquei os vídeos no mysql e quero reproduzi-los, não achei nenhuma forma de reproduzi-los maleavelmente.
A única forma que eu consegui foi assim: https://playex.link/painel/upload/test.php?id=426612290166

Vocês sabem como posso criar um link para colocar na tag ?

Exemplo:

```
<video src="blob://playex.link/v/2389akjf0-12kjr-1ed22=d123-2sed1"/>
```

Comment: quando você diz que quer colocar um link, o que realmente quer dizer? Transformar o `test.php?id=426612290166` de forma amigável? Seria isso?

Comment: Não, estou querendo criar um link para meu vídeo que está em no mysql na forma de um blob. Esse link de teste que coloquei é só pra vocês verem como está até agora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sei que não é da minha conta, mas isso no futuro quando seu site crescer vai te causar muita dor de cabeça.

falo por experiência propia, tive problemas com isto.
eu salvava músicas no mysql, sei que deu uma sobrecarga muito tensa tive que desativar o site por 3 dias e passar tudo para arquivos, perdi bastante usuários.

se eu fosse você salvaria tudo em pastas, exemplo tenho o arquivo wesley.mp4 uso a função `md5()` nele, gerará uma string 4f755db8796988ecf1a3dba1c0cc584d

após isto você usa um `substr('4f755db8796988ecf1a3dba1c0cc584d',0,2);` irá retornar 4f.

com isto você cria uma pasta chamada 4f no php existe funções que criam a pasta se ela não existir.
então ficaria assim **/uploads/4f/wesley.mp4**
neste caso vários arquivos poderão ter 4f no inicio da md5.

então você pode salvar milhares de arquivos em subpastas que não irá ficar pesado, como eu fiz na imagem abaixo.

[image: a primeira string do arquivo sempre é a ou 1]

a primeira string do arquivo sempre é 'a' ou '1', ele irá meio que agrupar todas as strings com 1 ou a nesta pasta, atualmente tenho cerca de 700 mil arquivos mp3 nestas pastas.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado! Meu problema é que não tenho permissão para fazer upload em arquivos na minha hospedagem e ela é muito barata e muito, muito boa mesmo! Por isso estou usando o mysql, além disso posso migrar facilmente etc... Mas muito obrigado pela ideia, estou a 2 meses com esse problema e pesquisei muito, MUITO MESMO, se eu realmente não conseguir irei usar. Vlw men!

Comment: obrigado pela edição @Andrei Coelho minha primeira resposta ainda estoua aprendendo a usar

Comment: Boa sorte amigo, espero que consiga, recomendo também usar mongodb ou elasticsearch para armazenar os dados do vídeo, em grande volume se monstram muito bom alem da interface de busca ficar muito mais amigável